# Find elements which have a specific child with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

With BeautifulSoup, **how to access to a `<li>` which has a specific `div` as child?**

Example: How to access to the text (i.e. info@blah.com) of the `li` which has `Email` as child div?

```
<li>
  <div>Country</div>
  Germany
</li>
<li>
  <div>Email</div>
  info@blah.com
</li>
```

*I tried to do it manually: looping on all `li`, and for each of them, relooping on all child `div` to check if text is Email, etc. but I'm sure there exists a more clever version with BeautifulSoup.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach the problem.

One option is to locate the `Email` div *by text* and get the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.find("div", text="Email").next_sibling.strip()  # prints "info@blah.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Question is about the get the whole `<li>` part which has "Email" inside the `<div>` tag right? Meaning you need to get the following result,

```
 <li>
  <div>Email</div>
  info@blah.com
 </li>
```

If I am understanding you question correctly means you need to do the following thing.

```
soup.find("div", text="Email").parent
```

or if you need "info@blah.com" as your result you need to do the following thing.

```
soup.find("div", text="Email").next_sibling
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a single div has content "Email", you can do this way.

```
soup.find("div", text="Email").find_parent('li')
```