# How to find elements with child anchor only?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

Using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) v4, I've some `td` elements, some of which contain a child `a` element.

```
<tr class="">
    <td class="tblimg"><img alt="" src="/blah/deficon.png"/></td>
    <td><a href="https://blah.com/file-25013.xhtml"><b>file.mp3</b></a><br/><span
            style="color: grey;">76.33 MB<br/>33129 Downloads<br/>55:34 Mins<br/>192kbps Stereo</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is there a good way to find only those `td` that have a child `a`? Currently, I'm iterating over all of them and discarding the ones for which `td.find("a")` doesn't exist.

Comment: Are the anchors always directly within the `<td>`? I'd grab on CSS selector `td > a`, then grab the parent for each element you find.

Comment: @ggorlen "_Are the anchors always directly within the <td>_" Yes. But `row.find_all("td > a")` finds nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find elements which have a specific child with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295451/find-elements-which-have-a-specific-child-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: `find_all` doesn't accept a CSS selector like that. You probably want `bs.select("td > a")`

Comment: @ggorlen The link you posted doesn't help. The accepted answer finds all the `div`s without regard for who the parents are.

Comment: Yeah but it's the same problem, fundamentally. If the answers there aren't satisfactory, we can improve them. How is `[x.parent for x in bs.select("td > a")]` (which is basically the second answer in the linked thread, extrapolated to your specific scenario)?

Comment: @ggorlen `select` returns a `ResultSet`, not a `Tag`, and `ResultSet` has no `parent`. I'll update my question with the table row, see for yourself.

Comment: I just ran this code on your HTML and it gave the desired result, `[<td><a href="https://blah.com/file-25035.xhtml"><b>file.mp3</b></a><br/><span style="color: grey;">32.44 MB<br/>10455 Downloads<br/>35:25 Mins<br/>128kbps Stereo</span></td>]`. `ResultSet` itself has no parent, but if you iterate each element and call `parent` on it, it works. If you just want one element, use `bs.select_one("td > a").parent`.

Comment: @ggorlen It does work, if you post as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although you already have the answer, I would like to provide another solution for your reference:)

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''<table><tr class="">
    <td class="tblimg"><img alt="" src="/blah/deficon.png"/></td>
    <td><a href="https://blah.com/file-25013.xhtml"><b>file.mp3</b></a><br/><span
            style="color: grey;">76.33 MB<br/>33129 Downloads<br/>55:34 Mins<br/>192kbps Stereo</span>
    </td>
</tr></table>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)  # create doc
# First get all a in the table, and then take the parent of a. All the data can be retrieved at one time.
tds = doc.selects('table>a').parent

print (tds)
```

Result:

```
[{'tag': 'td', 'html': '<a href="https://blah.com/file-25013.xhtml"><b>file.mp3</b></a><br /><span style="color: grey;">76.33 MB<br />33129 Downloads<br />55:34 Mins<br />192kbps Stereo</span>\n    '}]
```